# Adding the selected feature on the map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

How can I add the selected county on the map?

```
var states = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/States")
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/Counties")

var statesNames = states.aggregate_array('NAME')

var getCounties = function(state) {
  // Given a state get all counties
  var feat = ee.Feature(states.filterMetadata('NAME', 'equals', state).first())
  var statefp = ee.String(feat.get('STATEFP'))
  var filteredCounties = counties.filterMetadata('STATEFP', 'equals', statefp)
  var filteredCountiesNames = filteredCounties.aggregate_array('NAME')
  return ee.List(filteredCountiesNames)
}

// Empty Dropdowns
var statesDD = ui.Select([], 'Loading..')
var countiesDD = ui.Select([], 'Waiting for a state..')

// Load states
statesNames.evaluate(function(states){
  statesDD.items().reset(states)
  statesDD.setPlaceholder('Select a state')
  statesDD.onChange(function(state){
    // once you select a state (onChange) get all counties and fill the dropdown
    countiesDD.setPlaceholder('Loading...')
    var counties = getCounties(state)
    counties.evaluate(function(countiesNames){
      countiesDD.items().reset(countiesNames)
      countiesDD.setPlaceholder('Select a county')
   Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(countiesDD))
    })
  })
})

ui.root.insert(0, ui.Panel([statesDD, countiesDD]));
```

link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d4c8625f6723ce1c59098a0e3bf8d3df

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an extra button for adding the county, since you can check if you selected the county you want or not. This is how:

```
var add = ui.Button('add county')
add.onClick(function(){
  var name = countiesDD.getValue()
  var county = ee.Feature(counties.filterMetadata('NAME', 'equals', name).first())
  Map.addLayer(county, {}, name)
})

ui.root.insert(0, ui.Panel([statesDD, countiesDD, add]));
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0340e4bd8cc686a566bd65c4263fbd2a)

But if you want to add it when you select it, you can do this:

```js
countiesDD.onChange(function(name){
  var county = ee.Feature(counties.filterMetadata('NAME', 'equals', name).first())
  Map.addLayer(county, {}, name)
})

ui.root.insert(0, ui.Panel([statesDD, countiesDD])
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/651d0c8b522e29925b35c7beb1030469)